# How to create a Pandas DataFrame from a list of lists with different lengths?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data in the format as follows

```
data = [["a", "b", "c"],
        ["b", "c"],
        ["d", "e", "f", "c"]]
```

and I would like to have a DataFrame with all unique strings as columns and binary values of occurrence as such

```
    a  b  c  d  e  f
0   1  1  1  0  0  0
1   0  1  1  0  0  0
2   0  0  1  1  1  1
```

I have a working code using list comprehensions but it's pretty slow for large data.

```
# vocab_list contains all the unique keys, which is obtained when reading in data from file
df = pd.DataFrame([[1 if word in entry else 0 for word in vocab_list] for entry in data])
```

Is there any way to optimise this task? Thanks.

EDIT (a small sample of actual data):

[['a',
  'about',
  'absurd',
  'again',
  'an',
  'associates',
  'writes',
  'wrote',
  'x',
  'york',
  'you',
  'your'],
 ['a',
  'abiding',
  'age',
  'aggravated',
  'aggressively',
  'all',
  'almost',
  'alone',
  'already',
  'also',
  'although']]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For better performance use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html):

```
data = [["a", "b", "c"],
        ["b", "c"],
        ["d", "e", "f", "c"]]

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer    
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(data),columns=mlb.classes_)
print (df)
   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  1  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  1  0  0  0
2  0  0  1  1  1  1
```

EDIT:

```
data = [['a', 'about', 'absurd', 'again', 'an', 'associates', 'writes', 'wrote', 'x', 'york', 'you', 'your'], ['a', 'abiding', 'age', 'aggravated', 'aggressively', 'all', 'almost', 'alone', 'already', 'also', 'although']]

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer    
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(data),columns=mlb.classes_)
print (df)
   a  abiding  about  absurd  again  age  aggravated  aggressively  all  \
0  1        0      1       1      1    0           0             0    0   
1  1        1      0       0      0    1           1             1    1   

   almost  ...  also  although  an  associates  writes  wrote  x  york  you  \
0       0  ...     0         0   1           1       1      1  1     1    1   
1       1  ...     1         1   0           0       0      0  0     0    0   

   your  
0     1  
1     0  

[2 rows x 22 columns]
```

Pure pandas solution is possible, but I guess it should be slowier:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(data), prefix='', prefix_sep='').max(level=0, axis=1)
print (df)
   a  b  d  c  e  f
0  1  1  0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0  1  0  0
2  0  0  1  1  1  1

df = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(data), prefix='', prefix_sep='').max(level=0, axis=1)
print (df)
   a  abiding  about  absurd  age  again  aggravated  aggressively  an  all  \
0  1        0      1       1    0      1           0             0   1    0   
1  1        1      0       0    1      0           1             1   0    1   

   ...  writes  alone  wrote  already  x  also  york  although  you  your  
0  ...       1      0      1        0  1     0     1         0    1     1  
1  ...       0      1      0        1  0     1     0         1    0     0  

[2 rows x 22 columns]
```

Comment: for the mlb solution, is there a way I can match the columns back to the vocab_list? It seems to work well with this small example I contrived, but with my actual data with longer strings in the lists, the columns appeared as strange labels like "aaaa" and "aaallll". I have added an example of my actual data.

Comment: ah it was just me being presumptuous. Those strange labels turn out to be strange words in in my data. Thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `join` in a list comprehension, and [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df = pd.Series(['|'.join(x) for x in data]).str.get_dummies()
```

[out]

```
   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  1  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  1  0  0  0
2  0  0  1  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of curiosity I timed the suggested solutions:

```
from string import ascii_letters
from random import choice, randint
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

data = []
for _ in range(10000):
    data.append([choice(ascii_letters) for _ in range(randint(25, 65))])

print("Time using 'pd.Series' and 'str.get_dummies()':")
startTime = datetime.now()
df = pd.Series(['|'.join(x) for x in data]).str.get_dummies()
print(datetime.now() - startTime)

print("Time using 'pd.get_dummies()':")
startTime = datetime.now()
df2 = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(data), prefix='', prefix_sep='').max(level=0, axis=1)
print(datetime.now() - startTime)

print("Time using 'MultiLabelBinarizer()':")
startTime = datetime.now()
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df3 = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(data),columns=mlb.classes_)
print(datetime.now() - startTime)
```

Although the results are going to be different each time as I'm using random lengths of lists, the differences will be more or less the same:

```
Time using 'pd.Series' and 'str.get_dummies()':
0:00:00.450311
Time using 'pd.get_dummies()':
0:00:00.498003
Time using 'MultiLabelBinarizer()':
0:00:00.083955
```

So, indeed, with the use of sklearn you can get a lot faster results.